# jQuery animation&google map combatibility issue

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to use JQuery hide() & slideDown() function to hide/display my google map. Everything works perfect for the map except after the slide down animation, the map is not well displayed.
Here's my code:

```
$("#map_canvas").hide();
...
...
...
$("#map_canvas").show(200);
```

(I used show() in this case, but it should work the same as slideDown()).
The map comes out like this:
...sh*t, I'm not qualified to upload images...
well, the map is just partially displayed, with other map area in gray color.

The strange thing is, when I try to "inspect element", the map just goes back to normal.
I've tried on Firefox and Chrome, same issue.

I also have another small issue. Chrome doesn't seem to work well with geolocation. I tried geolocation on all major browsers, only Chrome gives me a wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the `resize`-event of the map inside the callback of `show()`

To help with the other issue we need more informations.